# If $f$ is injective, then $\ker T(f)\subseteq \tau(T(M))$ (Exercise 8 Bourbaki Algebra $\S 5$)

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I've been attempting to solve the following question:

> Let $A$ be an integral domain. Let $f:M\rightarrow N$ be a injective $A$-homomorphism of $A$-modules. Then, show that $\ker T(f)\subseteq \tau(T(M))$.

Here $T(M)$ is the tensor algebra $\bigoplus_{n\geq 0}T^n M$ and $T(f)$ is the $A$-homomorphism $T(M)\rightarrow T(N)$ induced by $f$ (for an element $x=x_1\otimes\cdots\otimes x_n\in T^nM,$ it follows that $ T(f)(x_1\otimes\cdots\otimes x_n)=f(x_1)\otimes\cdots\otimes f(x_n)$). Lastly, $\tau(R)$ denotes the torsion submodule of a $A$-module $R$.

---

I've been trying to solve this for quite some time now, and have been consistently getting stuck. I believe the following properties might be useful (stated in Bourbaki):

> 1. For a $A$-homomorphism $f:M\rightarrow N$, $f(\tau(M))\subseteq \tau(N)$.
> 2. Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$. Then for the canonical homomorphism $\phi:M\rightarrow K\otimes M$ defined as $x\mapsto 1\otimes x,$ we have that $\ker \phi=\tau(M)$.
> 3. For a $A$-homomorphism $f:M\rightarrow N$, it follows that $K\otimes \ker f=\ker (1_K\otimes f)$. In particular, $1_K\otimes f$ is injective if and only if $\ker f\subseteq \tau(M)$.
> 4. Lastly, the functor $M\mapsto K\otimes M$ is exact, that is, $K$ is flat. (More generally, $S^{-1}:M\mapsto S^{-1}M$ is an exact functor)

Whenever I try anything, it just keep becoming circular.. any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What is $\tau$ here?

Comment: Oh! $\tau(M)$ denotes the torsion submodule of $M$. I will put that in.

Comment: Hint: Localize at the zero ideal.